# MySQL - DELETE FROM with subquery

Tags: mysql

im trying to execute this query but i'm getting error #1064.

```
delete from tableABC WHERE ID in (select ID from `TABLEXYZ` where `qty` = 0);
```

But the following statement works

> select * from tableABC WHERE ID in (select ID from `TABLEXYZ` where
>   `qty` = 0);

Comment: then how about `delete from tableABC WHERE ID in (select ID from TABLEXYZ where qty = 0);`

Comment: what is the differences between my query? it's just lack of the backtick

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer:

to use a delete query with subquery which has a where condition, do the following:

```
DELETE a FROM `tableABC` AS a JOIN (SELECT ID FROM `tableXYZ` WHERE `qty`=0) as b on b.ID = a.ID
```

Comment: THis is right -- the key part is that by naming the subquery 'b' you force it to get persisted to a temporary table (invisibly handled by the sql engine). To do deletes using a subquery, it's necessary that the subquery gets temporarily persisted.